# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'creation_datetime' in class 'Category' clashes with field of the same name from base class 'BaseClass

Tags: django-models

```
class BaseClass(models.Model):
    slugId = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creation_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slugId = slugify(self.name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        

class Category(BaseClass):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 150)

class Product(BaseClass):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

when I used python manage.py migrate, that time occur the problem. have any solution ?
advance thanks...

Comment: Had you generated any migrations before you declared `BaseClass` as abstract?